# Check for existence of an OCR table without using the read_pdf function?

Tags: python, pdf, ocr, python-camelot

Currently using camelot to populate a dictionary like so:

```
tables = camelot.read_pdf(temp_file_path)
tables_dict = {}

if tables.n > 0:
    for i, table in enumerate(tables, start=1):
        table_key = f"Table{i}"
        df = table.df
        table_rows = []

        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            row_dict = row.to_dict()
            row_dict = {str(key): value for key, value in row_dict.items()}
            table_rows.append(row_dict)

        tables_dict[table_key] = table_rows
```

This block runs on every page of the PDFs I use, which are usually around 1,000 pages. Only a few dozen of them include tables. Is there a way to check for the existence of a table without using the read_pdf function? The invocation on pure text pages slows down the application considerably.

Comment: One idea would be to count how many [drawings](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes-drawing-and-graphics.html) there are on each page, and don't bother running table detection on pages with too few drawings. This is not exactly what you want to do, but detecting tables in PDFs is not an exact science. There's no equivalent of the `<table>` tag in PDFs.